# Getting tagid from tagname

Tags: template-tags

Currently I am working on a rating plugin. You can see the code I got so far below:

```
<?php if (function_exists('get_highest_rated')): ?>
<ul>
<?php get_highest_rated_tag(12, 'both', 0, 10); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But now it comes to a bit of php that I simply can't find on the web so far, so I will ask you.

At this code, you see the number 12, that is the tag id. But I can't put in the tag name.

So I was thinking of echo'ing the tagid for a certain tagname. Is this possible? This way I can get like $tagid of that certain tagname and insert it into the code above.

Answer (score 2):

[get_term_by()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) might help you here.

```
$tag = get_term_by('id', 12, 'post_tag'); //or whatever taxonomy you are using 
echo $tag->name;
```

Comment: Dear Rrikesh,Thank you for your reply. But I want it the other way around. I got the tag name in $tagname. And I want to get the ID of that tag.

Comment: you can use `$tag = get_term_by('name', $your_term_name, 'post_tag')`. Then use `$tag->term_id` to get the ID.

Comment: I tried this, look at the answer of Rohit Pande, but it seems it does not work, does it matter that it's in the sidebar?

Comment: Use `get_query_var('post_tag'))` to get your term when you are outside the loop.

Comment: Rrikesh, could you give me some more code, cause I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Try `echo get_query_var('post_tag');` to see if you get your term. Sorry for the one `)` in excess in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_term_by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) function of wordpress.

Syntax:

```
<?php get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter ) ?>
```

Ex.

```
// Get term by name ''news'' in Categories taxonomy.
get_term_by('name', 'news', 'category')
```

Assign the output to some variable and use that variable instead of your tag ID. (in your case 12)

**EDIT**

In the answer I have provided you an example. So go through the parameters first.

You can do something like this:

`$tag_desc = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'post_tag');`

then use, `echo "<pre>"; print_r($tag_desc); echo "</pre>";` to display all the description of the tag and depending upon the parameter you set for the output field, you will get the output as object or array.

Iterate through the result and access the `term_id` for the tag.

Ex. `$tag_desc->term_id;`

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. I don't use a certain category, I want to get it for a certain tag? The output to some variable is exactly what I want, but I don't see how I can get the tag id of $tagname by this code. Would you care to explain a bit more for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So are you able to get the ID by now? if you want to display the ID you can simply use `echo $tag_desc->term_id;`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I came alittle further, but I am not that good with php. This is what I got so far:<br/>

<?php if (function_exists('get_highest_rated')): ?>
    <ul><?php $tag_desc = get_term_by('name', $site_domain, 'post_tag'); ?>
    <?php get_highest_rated_tag(($tag_desc->term_id), 'both', 0, 10); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>


yes I got the id by now, but I can't use $site_domain at this?: <?php $tag_desc = get_term_by('name', $site_domain, 'post_tag'); ?>

Comment: what is the value of your `$site_domain` variable?
are you sure that it is a valid tag?

Comment: I'm using $site_domain throughout the website, it gives back the correct keywords for this theme as it's for my own network of websites. An example where it works is: 
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $site_domain ) ); ?>

Comment: $site_domain returns www.website.nl but without the www. and .nl. so it returns website. Which I also have as tag for the posts for that website.

Comment: can you `echo` or `print_r` the value of `$site_domain` and make sure that it is a valid tag associated with the post?

Comment: Rohit Pande, could you give me the exact code to echo or print_r the value of $site_domain? Then I'll put it in place.

Comment: You can just make it work like, `echo $site_domain;` or if its an array you can use like, `echo '<pre>'; print_r($site_domain);echo '</pre>';`
You can put this statement before your `<?php $tag_desc = get_term_by('name', $site_domain, 'post_tag'); ?>` statement.

Comment: If I use the echo or the echo with print, it doesn't show anything. It is in sidebar.php, does that change anything?

Comment: It means that your `$site_domain` has no value. So you have lot of work to do now.
I will list the steps but you need to learn the coding part for it so search some tutorials.
1. List all the tags for the post using [wp_get_post_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags)
2. Iterate through the result
3. use the get_term_by function to get the tag id
4. then pass this ID to your function `get_highest_rated_tag`

Comment: Rohit, don't you find it strange that I can use this on 2 other locations, for the menu and for the index to show posts from a certain tag, but not for this?

Comment: I am not having your exact code and theme setup with me so I am trying to help you as far as possible. As you are not getting any value in your `$site_domain` variable, I have provided you the possible solution.

Comment: Dear Rohit Pande, I tried something different. I added: <?php global $site_domain; ?> before the code and now it works. I got it in my header aswell, any tips so I only need this code 1 time on my page? Like, why doesn't it take it from the header.php?

Comment: In your `header.php` that variable must be used in a local scope of the function. You can access the variable anywhere you want. There is no harm.

Comment: Rohit, that's quite strange. Cause I have it in my header.php, but when I don't have it in my sidebar.php it simply doesn't work... any thoughts on that?

Comment: As I have already specified that the variable used in the `header.php` must have been used for local scope of the function . For accessing the value in the sidebar you can use the code `<?php global $site_domain; ?>` whenever needed.